# как обрезать эту строку?

Tags: php

Как обрезать строку чтобы выдавало только "**PBcqVio2ado**" ?
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBcqVio2ado"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так как параметры могут идти в произвольном порядке, лучше воспользоваться двумя функциями [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) и [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php).

```php
<?php

function getHashYoutube($url) {
    parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $output);

    if (!isset($output['v'])) {
        return false;
    }


    return $output['v'];
}
```

**Пример использования**

```php
<?php

echo getHashYoutube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBcqVio2ado') . "\n"; // PBcqVio2ado

echo getHashYoutube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBcqVio2ado&feature=youtu.be') . "\n"; // PBcqVio2ado

echo getHashYoutube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=PBcqVio2ado') . "\n"; // PBcqVio2ado

echo getHashYoutube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature[]=youtu.be&v=PBcqVio2ado') . "\n"; // PBcqVio2ado
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно так:

```
 $data = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBcqVio2ado";
 $temp = explode("=", $data);
 echo $temp[1];
```

Comment: Не решает. Самый простой случай https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBcqVio2ado&feature=youtu.be — вернет не то.

Comment: Да, но задание было в конкретной строке.

Comment: Если бы ему нужно было бы это сделать для этой конкретной строки — он бы в ручную это сделал...

Comment: Я говорю в плане того, что автору не нужны столь сложные адресные строки, а конкретно такого типа =)

Answer (score 1):

> Можно так:

```
$rest = substr("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBcqVio2ado", -11);
```

Answer (score 1):

Могут быть два вида ссылок:

```
$data = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBcqVio2ado"; // первый вариант
$data2 = "https://youtu.be/PBcqVio2ado";  // Второй вариант

$link1 = substr($data, strpos($data, "v=") + 2);  // для первого
$link2 = substr($data, strpos($data, "e/") + 2);   // для второго
```